# Runtime error 104 Pascal

Tags: pascal, freepascal

Im very new to using files and im really struggling to fix this any help would be great.
It seems that the error is coming from my read array function but not entirely 
sure i am also not to sure what the 104 error really means
thanks in advance

```
 program ReadFromFile;


type
    lineArray = array [0..19] of String;

procedure PrintArray(lines: lineArray);
var
    i: Integer;
begin
    for i:=0 to High(lines) do
    begin
        WriteLn('Text is: ', lines[i], ' Line number is: ', i);
    end;
end;

function ReadArray(var myFile: TextFile):lineArray;
var 
    count : Integer;
    lines : lineArray;
    i: Integer;
begin
    ReadLn(myFile, count);
    for i := 0 to count do
    begin
        ReadLn(myFile, lines[i]);
    end;
    result := lines;
end;

procedure Main();
var
    myFile: TextFile;
    line: lineArray;
begin

    AssignFile(myFile, 'mytestfile.dat');
    ReWrite(myFile);
    line:=ReadArray(myFile);
    Close(myFile);

    AssignFile(myFile, 'mytestfile.dat');
    Reset(myFile);
    PrintArray(line);
    Close(myFile);
end;

begin
  Main();
end.
```

Comment: Not related to the error, but you are reading past the number of counts. `0 to count-1` is the correct loop range when reading the file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't know what that error means. Neither do I off the top of my head.  So, let's look it up in the documentation and find out. Websearch takes us here: https://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/user/userap4.html

> #### File not open for input
>
> Reported by Read, BlockRead, Eof, Eoln, SeekEof or SeekEoln if the file is not opened with Reset.

You have your calls to open the file the wrong way round. Call `Reset` to open for reading, `Rewrite` to open for writing.

Notes:

- Looping from 0 to `count` will perform `count + 1` iterations. I'd expect to see you looping from 0 to `count - 1`.
- You don't check whether your array is long enough. You therefore run the risk of a buffer overrun. A dynamic array would avoid this.
- It's not clear why you open the file for a second time when you print the contents to the console.
- You could have looked up the error code yourself. Please take the hint to do web search the next time you encounter an error like this.

Comment: Thanks for the very helpful response, i did do some research but not knowing much about working with files i was not to sure what Reset did or how it was used Thanks again.

Comment: Again, `Reset` is covered by the documentation. And in every introduction to Pascal I/O. It would serve you well to concentrate on improving your web search skills.

Comment: Alright next time ill definitely have a better look around before posting sorry for an inconvenience